# Automating the process of creating a steam lobby (for dota) and inviting users to it

Tags: steam, ruby, webapp

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails web-application and I want to create lobbies and send invitations to users to join these lobbies. Simply, I want to achieve `ISteamMatchmaking Interface` functionality of `Steam SDK` but the problem is that sdk in written in C/C++ and I would have to write wrapper to integrate sdk in my application.

My question is that is there some easy and less time consuming approach to achieve `ISteamMatchmaking Interface` functionality in web-application?

I'm using RoR but I'm open to use other technologies too.